# Firebase setCustomUserClaims is always overriding the old one

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

In firebase i wish to use custom user claims to set user role, and also modules that user able to access.

If user is admin, the custom claim would be:

```
{isAdmin: true}
```

Then now i grant the admin able to access user module, in my cloud function codes:

```
exports.grantUserAccess = functions.https.onCall((data)=> {
  return firebase.auth().setCustomUserClaims(data.uid, {
    hasUserModule: true
  }).then(() => {
    return 'complete'
  })
})
```

So what i expect would be:

```
{isAdmin: true, hasUserModule: true}
```

But when i print out the user claims, it seems that `isAdmin: undefined`, then `hasUserModule: true`, it basically overrides the old claims, why is that?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation on custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk):

> Note: this operation always overwrites the user's existing custom
>   claims. However, if the same custom user claims are defined on a user
>   signed in via custom authentication, the overlapping claims defined in
>   the custom token have higher priority and always overwrite the custom
>   user claims defined on a user via this API.

So, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: And it's the problem when you have custom claims and try to use firebase stripe extension (adding stripeRole removes your custom claims). Are there any plans to change it in the future?

Comment: If you don't like the way the extension works, you can always file an issue on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/extensions